# How to remove (colon) : after SKU on the product page? in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to remove the  (colon)  : after SKU from the product display page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .product-info-main .product.sku .type:after {
    content: ' ' !important;
}
```

Comment: by using this css i was removed that :(colon) after css

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove by css :

```
product-info-main .product.sku .type:after { content: ' ' !important; }
```

use this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

add below code in `<body>` tag

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
```

Comment: not sku colon after sku

Comment: i got the solution with css

Comment: you can find that Colon inside attributes. Stores > Attributes > Product >SKU Attribute.